# UITableView reloadRows cause crash some times

Tags: swift, uitableview

Sometimes when I use reloadRows in UITableView, it causes a crash. The error message I see on Firebase is:

NSInternalInconsistencyException - Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (18) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (17), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

It seems to be related to an inconsistency with the data source. However, when I click on a cell, I don't perform any other insert or delete operations. While I don't encounter this crash often in my own testing, there is a significant occurrence of this crash reported on Firebase.

Here is my code:

```
extension UITableView {

    func indexPathIsValid(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        let section = indexPath.section
        let row = indexPath.row
        return section >= 0 && section < numberOfSections && row >= 0 && row < numberOfRows(inSection: section)
    }

    func reloadCellForExpandArticle(at indexPath: IndexPath, isExpanded: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            defer {
                completion?()
            }
            UIView.performWithoutAnimation { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self,
                      self.indexPathIsValid(indexPath) else { return }
                
                self.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
       
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.sizeToFit()

                
                guard self.rectForRow(at: indexPath).minY <= self.bounds.minY,
                      !isExpanded
                else { return }
                self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help in identifying the cause of this crash since it's difficult for me to pinpoint the issue, especially considering the discrepancy between my own testing and the number of crashes reported on Firebase.

I have tried adding performBatchUpdates when calling reloadRows, but the number of crashes remains the same.

```
self.performBatchUpdates {
     self.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is due to the `DispatchQueue.main.async` calls... First, you call `completion?()` in a `defer`, so it should be called just after `performWithoutAnimation()`, not after the call inside it has been called, which i guess isn't intended. The issue is then linked to the fact that `tableView.numberOfSections` can differs from tableView.datasource.numberOfSection(_ tableView:)`, because there is some kind of "cache".